# Filter and z-index (IE7)

Tags: internet-explorer, css, internet-explorer-7

I am applying a filter to achieve gradients on a div. Inside the element, there is another element that is supposed to overlap the other element. To do this I use `z-index`.

This works in all (the ones I test) browsers except IE7 
    `filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient( startColorstr='#3595d0', endColorstr='#004193',GradientType=0 );`

```
/*Close button inside the element with the filter*/
 .close-button {
    position: relative;
    float: right;
    display: inline-block;
    margin: -10px;
    width: 22px;
    height: 22px;
    cursor: pointer;
    z-index: 2000;
}
```

This works if I remove the filter from my code. In IE7 I could live without the filter but it would be nice in IE7+. Why is this happening? Is there any workaround?

edit: se fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/pethel/HPPh2/5/ . In my case the x is an image. I cant open the fiddle in IE7 here. Have no idea why.

Comment: It's not really clear what you are asking. Also, it would be helpful for you to set up a JSFiddle that replicates the problem so we can troubleshoot it more easily.

Comment: Yup - we'll need to see all the relevant HTML and CSS, i.e. the CSS for the element with the filter, and the HTML for both elements.

Comment: honestly, I would not make the effort... IE8 is not supported anymore by most companies when building new websites, support for IE7 was dropped a loooong time ago. You should have a really good reason if you want to take the effort to even open up IE7.

Comment: @Ennui Please see my fiddle in the edit.

Comment: @giorgio If it was up to me I would have dropped it.

Comment: Use http://jsfiddle.net/pethel/HPPh2/5/show/ to view in IE7. Can you add a screenshot of your page showing the problem?

Answer (score 0):

Filter in IE7 emulate haslayout using activex.
It brings element up to front.

try to apply filter to the button as well (i have no more IE7, just goood or bad memories of its behavior)

http://liveweave.com/x3GVng  (you should be abble to see it in IE7 (do not try to edit though, use later browser)

Comment: Thanks I will try that tomorrow. The X should be outside the bar. The problem is that the part that is outside disappears when a filter is applied to the parent. The X is an image in real life.

Comment: Okay, so the problem: filter = haslayout = overflow:hidden :)

Comment: Can this be fixed? An explanation or link would be very helpful.

Comment: When you apply a filter to IE7 (inherited behavior from older version) it gets haslayout turned on with some sides effect . I'm getting confused, is your fiddle really the code your having problem with ? X stands inside container not outside ? Are you testing with a real stand alone IE7 ? is there any : position:relative involved in parent ?

Comment: http://www.satzansatz.de/cssd/onhavinglayout.html (overflow:visible could be a fixed for IE7 , i have doubts because of filter)  , you could find it yourself :)

Comment: overflow:visible  did not make any difference. I will continue try things. Maybe I have to live with no gradient in IE9.